# Error cannot convert argument 1 from 'int[][3] to int(&&)[3][3]'

Tags: c++, list

Can anyone solve this for me? I couldn't find why is it giving error on these specific lines. I guess the syntax is right. I have commented the error lines. It is giving error on open.push_back(p) in DFID function and mylist.push_back(p); in GenerateChildren function Please help me on this. Much Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int n = 3;

int goal[n][n] = { { 1, 2, 3 },{ 8, 0, 4 },{ 7, 6, 5 } };

static int max_depth = 0;

list <int[3][3]> open;
list <string> closed;

bool DFID(int[3][3]);
list<int[3][3]> generateChildren(int[3][3]);
bool isGoal(int [3][3]);
string convertToString(int[3][3]);
bool inClosed(string);

void main()
{
    int puzzle[n][n] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 8, 6, 4 }, { 7, 0, 5 } };

    DFID(puzzle);

}

bool DFID(int p[3][3])
{

    open.push_back(p);  // Error on this line
    open.pop_front();

    list<int[3][3]> mylist = generateChildren(p);

    list<int[3][3]>::iterator it;

    for (it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (isGoal(*it))
            return true;
        else
        {
            string s =convertToString(*it);
            if (inClosed(s))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
            //  
            }
        }
    }


}

list<int[3][3]> generateChildren(int p[3][3])
{
    //finding zero element

    int a = 0, b = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < n; j++)
        {
            if (p[i][j] == 0)
            {
                a = i;
                b = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    list <int[3][3]> mylist;

    if (p[-a][b] != -1)
    {
        swap(p[a][b], p[--a][b]);
        mylist.push_back(p);   //Error on this line
    }

    if (p[a][--b] != -1)
    {
        swap(p[a][b], p[a][--b]);
        mylist.push_back(p);   //Error
    }

    if (p[++a][b] != 3)
    {
        swap(p[a][b], p[++a][b]);
        mylist.push_back(p);   //Error
    }

    if (p[a][++b] != 3)
    {
        swap(p[a][b], p[a][++b]);
        mylist.push_back(p);  //Error
    }
    return mylist;
}

bool isGoal(int p[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < n; j++)
        {
            if (p[i][j] != goal[i][j]);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

string convertToString(int p[3][3])
{
    string puzz;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            puzz = puzz + to_string(p[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return puzz;
}

bool inClosed(string s)
{
    list<string>::iterator it;

    for (it = closed.begin(); it != closed.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it == s);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems with the code as you show it.

One issue is that putting data into a container means it either needs to be move or copied. And arrays can't be neither moved nor copied.

Another issue is that e.g.

```
bool DFID(int[3][3]);
```

is equal to

```
bool DFID(int(*)[3]);
```

That is, the argument is a *pointer* and not an array. Pointers and arrays are different.

One possible way to solve your problems (both of them) is to use another standard container, such as [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<std::array<int, n>, n> goal;
std::list<std::array<std::array<int, n>, n>> open;
```

You can simplify the type with a type-alias:

```
using matrix_type = std::array<std::array<int, n>, n>;
matrix_type goal;
std::list<matrix_type> open;
```